# VSCode Dart Import Shortcut

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter, angular-dart

Does VSCode and/or a plugin offer a keyboard shortcut to automatically add an import in a Dart file?  In IntelliJ and Android Studio this effect is easily achieved with Opt+Enter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you try to organize imports you can use `Alt+Shift+O`.

If you have a Type not recognised in the current file, you can use `Ctrl+.` (macOS: `Cmd+.`) to open Quick Fixes and select the imports you need (the searched import are dependent to your pubspec file).

See [the key bindings of the Dart extension](https://dartcode.org/docs/key-bindings/).

Comment: Anyway to make it add the import using package: instead of relative paths ?

Comment: very useful. Always used to get problem with this. Cmd and . solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the following Vscode extensions to auto import dependencies:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidwoo.flutter-auto-import